How can I tighten this double threaded fitting?
On our radiator this was leaking so I took it off, but I don't see how to get it back on tightly.
It screws in both ends, so I can screw it into both simultaneously but it will close on one end first and then not properly close on the other end. I don't see how to close it without doing both simultaneously.




For that use, I would expect half of it to be able to turn separately.  A solid fitting is really only good for single pipes/hoses where you can turn the pipe on after screwing into the rad/whatever.

Hard to tell from the pics, but isn't that a union?  The theads look like they go different directions.

If yours is a union like the American ones I have seen, the 'other' side should have ears on the inside. There is a not-so-special plumber's tool that goes inside and locks on the ears; you can then put a wrench on the tool to turn it.

The piece you are holding should be a union. If so, it disassembles; you would screw each half into its side of the connection, then reassemble the union to clamp the two together.
If somehow it isn't a union, then you need to add a union.

Probably a union that's been painted so much that the union nut isn't free to turn. Of course, that does beg the question of how it was removed. But it also suggests that removing the paint might make it work again.

@Ecnerwal: Or just replace it with a new union of the same size, which would have these advantage that you start with two pieces that you can see how to connect and disconnect. (And with clean, fresh threads.) At a guess: perhaps it slipped enough to permit disassembly?

This was it, thanks. Managed to get it off by screwing it into one end of the radiator very tightly, and then screwing it off and one end was left in the radiator.
